# No "Web Service Extensions" folder in IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit), after turning on the IIS 6 feature in Control Panel, there is no "Web Service Extension" folder in the IIS Manager. I need this to turn on the ASP feature. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: I set a virtual machine and installed Server 2003, IIS 6 looks normal under 2003. Now I got a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue recently. The solution is:

```
%WindowsDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%Framework_version%\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

PS not sure it works on IIS6, but you should definitely check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I also googled that command, however, I think it only works on Windows XP, when trying to run the same command on Windows 7, it ended up with some application error.

Comment: ehm... nope, I did it on my Windows 7 Ultimate x86, IIS7. Worked fine. Possible reason it had no effect is you use x64 Windows - make sure you launch aspnet_regiis.exe for 64 or 32 bit version (If there is a difference)